# How to do String Display Limitation in C#?

Tags: c#

Today I have Learned two things

1 - Displaying int to this format : 0001 in a text box

> Number.ToString("0000.");

2 - Displaying double to this format : £ 03.00 in a text box

> Price.ToString("£ 00.00");

my questions is: How to display a limitation of string in c#?

I mean is the value in a string is

```
string myString = "Hello World!"
```

I would like it to display 20 letters so it will display

```
"Hello World!        "
```

and if it was more than 20 letters it will skip displaying the rest
for example:

```
string myString = "I Love every thing you say :*"
```

it will only display the following:

```
"I Love every thing y"
```

20 Letters Maximum display (Counting the spaces)..

any idea?

Comment: "Displaying double to this format : £ 03.00 in a text box" That is almost never the right thing to do. Don't use `double` for currency, use `decimal`.

Comment: BTW - For showing literals, putting them in as code (indented 4 spaces) instead of quotes (using `>`) will cause the spacing to be preserved correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Substring or PadRight

```
int length = 20;
string original = "I Love every thing you say :*";

string finalString = original.Length > length ? 
                   original.Substring(0, length) : 
                   original.PadRight(length);
```

This will take the appropriate length substring, or pad with spaces, as needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
string myString = "I Love every thing you say :*"

string fixedWidth = string.Format("{0, -20}", (myString.Length > 20 ? myString.Substring(0,20) : myString));
```

As a string extension:

```
public static string ToFixedWidth(this string s, int length)
{
    return string.Format("{0, -20}, s.Length > length ? s.Substring(0, length) : s);
}
```

Comment: myString.ToString("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL"); ?

Comment: You could wrap my ternary in string extension method for ease of use.

Comment: This isn't going to handle the padding, and Substring(20) will give you the wrong string... (You need `Substring(0, 20)` (note casing, too)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use `myString.Substring(0,20)`. `Substring(20)` sets the start to 20, and not the end.

Comment: This still doesn't handle the padding.  Look at the "Hello world" sample requirements (note the space at the end)

Comment: @ReedCopsey I think that is typo, since "Hello World! " (with one extra space character) is only 13 characters long.

Comment: @jonnyGold It's not - it's a SO formatting issue.  Edit their post, and you can see they padded it with spaces to 20 chars

Comment: I just edited the post to make it obvious - there were 8 spaces in the original post after the ! before the closing quotation mark

Comment: I've updated the answer code to what should be the correct thing now.

Comment: @jonnyGOld You'd need to use `{0,-20}` to pad like the example ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
String.Format("{0,-20}", "Hello World!");
```

will give you what you need.

EDIT: Should be a comma

EDIT: Never mind, this will not trim. Perhaps combine with Substring:

```
String.Format("{0,-20}", "Hello World!").Substring(0,20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a string with 21 spaces and then remove to get the right length:

```
string formattedStr = (myString + new string(' ', 21)).Remove(20);
```